# Sort List of File Names with Different Amount of Characters

Tags: python, file, sorting, python-3.9

I'm running into a problem where I need a sorted list of files that are in the format xxx_00000, xxx_00001. The issue is that when there are more than 100000 files the format becomes xxx_100000 while all the others stay the same. This means that when I do os.listdir(directory) I get xxx_10000 next to xxx_100000 (i.e. xxx_10000 is index 10,000 and xxx_100000 is index 10,001). Any ideas on how to sort this so that they appear in the correct order?
I've tried:

```
sorted(paths)

sorted(paths, key=lambda x: x[x.rfind('_')+1:-4])
```

and

```
def sorted_helper(x):
    x = str(00000) + x[x.rfind('_')+1:-4]
    return x[-7:]

sorted(paths, key=sorted_helper)
```

Comment: Did you try `sorted(paths, key=lambda x: x[x.rfind('_')+1:])`? you shouldn't set an end-limit to your string, as I assume that's what's causing the issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`natsort.natsorted`](https://pypi.org/project/natsort/):

```
from natsort import natsorted

natsorted(paths)
```

Answer (score 2):

You presumably want to sort it as an int, not as a string. Try:

```py
sorted(paths, key=lambda filename: int(filename.split("_")[1]))
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`natsort`](https://pypi.org/project/natsort/) library can be helpful in such cases.

For example:

```
from natsort import natsorted

natsorted(paths)
```

Output:

```
['xxx_00001',
 'xxx_00002',
 'xxx_00100',
 'xxx_01000',
 'xxx_10000',
 'xxx_100001',
 'xxx_100010',
 'xxx_110000']
```